# Bootstrap Modal Not closing after successful Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am getting success in the Ajax Call but after submission, it is not hiding.

I tried `.hide();` `.modal('hide');`

Here is

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="addWorkModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addWorkModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addWorkModalLabel">Add Work</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="create-work-form">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ work_form|crispy }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-id">User ID:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-id" name="user" value="{{ client.user.id }}">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-work-button">Save Work</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
document.getElementById('save-work-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('create-work-form');
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    var url = "";
    console.log('URL being requested:', url);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("AJAX call successful"); // Debugging
            if (response.work) {
                $('#addWorkModal').modal('hide');
            } else {
                // Handle errors from response
                var errorText = 'Error creating work: ' + JSON.stringify(response.errors || 'Unknown error');
                console.error(errorText);  // Log error to the console instead of alerting
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var errorMsg = 'An error occurred. Status: ' + status + '. Error: ' + error;
            if(xhr.responseText) {
                errorMsg += '. Response: ' + xhr.responseText;
            }
            console.error(errorMsg);  // Log error to the console instead of alerting
        }
    });
});
```

**My question** after submitting the form how can I close or hide the modal automatically as it is not suppose to appear after submission.

Comment: Hi, what exactly `response` has in it ? Can you print it and check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
$('#addWorkModal').modal('hide');
```

with this:

```
document.getElementById('addWorkModal').style.display = 'none';
```

and tell me if it helped.

**EDIT:**

If the modal is not hiding as expected, there are a few things you can check:

1. Ensure jQuery is Loaded:

Make sure that jQuery is loaded before this script. You can include it in your HTML file before the script:

```html
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Your script here -->
<script>
    // Your script goes here
</script>
```

2. Check the Response:

Add a `console.log(response)` in your success callback to see what the server is returning. Make sure that the response is as expected and that the code inside the `if (response.work)` block is being executed.

3. Check for JavaScript Errors:

Open the browser console (usually F12 or right-click and "Inspect" then go to the "Console" tab) to check for any JavaScript errors. This might give you more information about what's going wrong.

4. Check Modal Element Existence:

Ensure that the modal element with the ID `addWorkModal` actually exists in the DOM. If it doesn't, jQuery won't find it, and the `modal('hide')` won't work.

**2nd EDIT:**

Create a CSS element `.hideModal`, like so:

```
.hideModal{display: none!important}
```

And then call it with the following JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("addWorkModal");
element.classList.add("hideModal");
```

Comment: it did not work

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few debugging tips.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution in the "2nd EDIT" part. Please, take a look and let me know if it works.